# Multiindex only some of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a csv which is generated in a format that I can not change. The file has a multi index. The file looks like this.

[image]

The end goal is to turn the top row (hours) into an index, and index it with the "ID" column, so that the data looks like this.

[image]

I have imported the file into pandas...

```
myfile = 'c:/temp/myfile.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, header=[0, 1], tupleize_cols=True)
pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns, names=['hour', 'field'])
df
```

But that gives me three unnamed fields:

[image]

My final step is to stack on hour:

```
df.stack(level=['hour'])
```

But I a missing what comes before that, where I can index the other columns, even though there's a blank multiindex line above them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the lines you are missing may be # 3 and 4:

```
df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('temp.csv', header = [0,1], tupleize_cols = True)
df.columns = [c for _, c in df.columns[:3]] + [c for c in df.columns[3:]]
df = df.set_index(list(df.columns[:3]), append = True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns, names = ['hour', 'field'])
```

1. Convert the tuples to strings by dropping the first value for first 3 col. headers.
2. Shelter these headers by placing them in an index.

After you perform the `stack`, you may reset the index if you like.

e.g.

Before

```
  (Unnamed: 0_level_0, Date)  (Unnamed: 1_level_0, id)  \
0                  3/11/2016                         5   
1                  3/11/2016                         6   

  (Unnamed: 2_level_0, zone)  (100, p1)  (100, p2)  (200, p1)  (200, p2)  
0                        abc      0.678      0.787      0.337      0.979  
1                        abc      0.953      0.559      0.776      0.520
```

After

```
field                        p1     p2
  Date      id zone hour              
0 3/11/2016 5  abc  100   0.678  0.787
                    200   0.337  0.979
1 3/11/2016 6  abc  100   0.953  0.559
                    200   0.776  0.520
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Yakym.

Comment: I am glad I could help.